# Construct a symmetric confidence interval for the acceleration coefficient

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, scipy, numpy

A machine model is tested in the factory to check the acceleration coefficient. The experiment selects n machines of this model and measures the distance traveled by the machine in 38 seconds. It is assumed that path measurement errors are independently equally distributed and have a distribution of 1/2 - exp(1). Construct a symmetric confidence interval for the acceleration coefficient. Input data: Two input values. The first is the confidence level, a number between 0 and 1. The second is a one-dimensional array numpy.ndarray of measurements in the path (in meters) of one model. Returned value: A tuple or a list of two values equal to the left and right boundaries of the confidence interval. I solved the problem this way:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def solution(p: float, x: np.array) -> tuple:

    x_bar = np.mean(x)
    s = np.std(x, ddof=1)
    z = norm.ppf(1 - (1 - p)/2)
    lower = x_bar - z * s / np.sqrt(len(x))
    upper = x_bar + z * s / np.sqrt(len(x))
    t = 38
    v = x.mean() / t
    a = 2 * v / t
    lower_a = 2 * lower / t
    upper_a = 2 * upper / t
    return lower_a, upper_a
```

But the length of the interval turns out to be long. How do I solve the problem so that it fits the conditions below.
[image]

Upd: The acceleration coefficient is the same as the acceleration.

Comment: What does "1/2 - exp(1)" mean?  Your code gives no clue.

Comment: If the condition says that X has a distribution C + (a distribution you know F like exp(1)), it means that X - C has a distribution F. In scipy such a transformation can be specified with loc = - C.

Comment: I'm afraid this makes very little sense to me.  In particular, if $X$ has an Exponential$(1)$ distribution, then $1/2-X$ (I presume that's what you are trying to describe) has a mean of $1/2-1=-1/2,$ which is not valid for a "measurement error." Part of the concept of a measurement error is that it is centered at $0.$ A nonzero mean represents a *systematic error.*